# How to use Page parameter with merge on php IMagick?

Tags: php

Merging 4 images with IMagick is working pretty good but setImagePage parameter is not working along merge. First or second page is resized but rest of files are remaining original size. On test environment dimensions of all files are same.
My goal is to resize all of pages to size of A4.

Here is the code:

$uploaded_files is an array of files and $refer is custom filename for merged file.

```
$pdf = new Imagick($uploaded_files);
$pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
$mergefile = 'files/' . $refer . '.pdf';
$pdf->setImagePage ( 595, 842 , 0,0 );
$filemerged = $pdf->writeImages($mergefile, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it by looping all files and setting pagesize individually on each image.

```
$pdf = new Imagick();

foreach( $uploaded_files as $f ) 
{ 
    //Create a new Imagick object
    $auxIMG = new Imagick(); 

    //Read single image
    $auxIMG->readImage($f); 

    //Rotate page if image width is higher that height
    if($auxIMG->getImageWidth() > $auxIMG->getImageHeight()){
        $transparent = '#ffffffff';
        $auxIMG->rotateImage($transparent, 90);
    }

    //Set pagesize A4
    $auxIMG->setImagePage ( 595, 842, 0,0 );

    //Add image to main object
    $pdf->addImage($auxIMG); 
} 
$filemerged = $pdf->writeImages($mergefile, true);
```